# replace old plot by new one

Tags: matlab, plot, subplot

let us consider following code

```
function [order]=find_order(y,fs);
order=0;
n=length(y);
n1=nextpow2(n);
ndft=2^n1;
for i=1:floor(n/2)
    [Pxx,f]=pburg(y,i,ndft,fs);
  % subplot(floor(n/2),floor(n/2),i);
   %subplot(ndft,ndft,i);
   h = figure; 
    plot(f,Pxx);
    title(['order',num2str(i),'i']);
    filename = 'mydata';
print(h, '-dpsc', filename);
    order(i)=i;    
    pause(6.21);
end
end
```

i have  one question want instead of at each iteration  plot new  graph,replace  old one by new one,so how can i do it?please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for loop you are calling for a new figure with every iteration with `h = figure`. If you really want to keep the function call, move it to outside the for loop

```
function [order]=find_order(y,fs);
order=0;
n=length(y);
n1=nextpow2(n);
ndft=2^n1;
```

**`h = figure;`**

```
for i=1:floor(n/2)
    [Pxx,f]=pburg(y,i,ndft,fs);
  % subplot(floor(n/2),floor(n/2),i);
   %subplot(ndft,ndft,i);

    plot(f,Pxx);
    title(['order',num2str(i),'i']);
    filename = 'mydata';
print(h, '-dpsc', filename);
    order(i)=i;    
    pause(6.21);
end
end
```

Comment: is it possible to save each  picture in one word document without outputing?